# how do i get "1994-01-01" from "1994" in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a year and I need to convert it to datetime formatted as Y-01-01. I have tried the following:

```
testdf = testdf = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1994]})
pd.to_datetime(testdf.A)
```

yields

```
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001994
```

Name: A, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Desired output would be this:

```
0   1994-01-01
```

I have also tried various configurements of format, unit etc but to no avail. I can only assume I must be missing something glaringly obvious as this seems like a fairly trivial task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the format as `%Y`:

```
pd.to_datetime(testdf.A, format='%Y')
```

then

```
0   1994-01-01
Name: A, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```